# adjusting brightness of image captured by USB camera module

Tags: camera

I am using USB camera module(model- ELP-USB130W01MT-L21) to capture the image which is interfaced with the Rpi( through SSh).
 Is there any way to adjust the brightness of the image captured??

Comment: What command are you using to capture the image? Have you checked the man page for that command man commandname?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install fswebcam` and `fswebcam image.jpg`. I am sorry, what is the manpage?

Comment: BTW you can read about what man pages are with the following command man man, which opens the man page for the man command. Also you should edit your question and include the answer to my question there not in the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the manual page (linux help system) for the fswebcam command by entering the following at the commandline:

```
man fswebcam
```

Under the list of options you will see

> −s, −−set
>
> Set a control. These are used by the source modules to control image
>   or device parameters. Numeric values can be expressed as a percentage
>   of there maximum range or a literal value, for example:
>
> −−set brightness=50% image.jpg

So to take a picture with 50% brightness you would use the following command:

```
fswebcam −−set brightness=50%
```

You should also read the **−−list−controls** section of the man page to check the current brightness setting and to confirm that brightness is controllable.